# Matching Two R Data Frames on Closeness

Tags: r, distance

I have the following two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = rep("A", 5),
                  name = c("Brandon",
                           "Kyler",
                           "Trent",
                           "Lesa",
                           "Michael"),
                  gender = c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M"),
                  days = c(50, 45, 32, 60, 48))

df2 <- data.frame(group = rep("B", 10),
                  name = c("Erica", 
                           "Jared",
                           "Sara",
                           "Helen",
                           "Tom",
                           "Ron",
                           "Cy",
                           "Lynn",
                           "Ken",
                           "Judy"),
                  gender = c("F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F"),
                  days = c(47, 49, 62, 80, 74, 30, 55, 58, 63, 25))
```

I want to filter `df2` to include only the closest match to each row in the `df1` data frame based on `gender` and `days`, with `gender` taking priority.

For example, in `df1`, "Brandon" has `gender == M` and `days == 50`. When we look at only `gender == M` in `df2`, we see that "Jared" is the closest to "Brandon" in days, so "Jared" would be selected for the "Brandon" match. In total, the resulting data frame would look like this:

```
# group  name gender days
#     B Jared      M   49
#     B Erica      F   47
#     B   Ron      M   30
#     B  Lynn      F   58
#     B    Cy      M   55
```

Additional rules:

- This is a hierarchical merge, where `gender` match takes priority over `days` closeness.
- Note that there are two equal distanced options to match to "Lesa" in `df1` ("Sara" and "Lynn"). Randomly select one of the two to match to "Lesa". In the final data frame above, the example chose "Lynn".
- "Jared" in `df2` is equal distance from both "Brandon" and "Michael" in `df1`. Because "Jared" is already matched to "Brandon", he cannot also be matched to "Michael". Therfore, the match to "Michael" moves on to "Cy", which is the next best remaining match in terms of `gender` and `days`.

Comment: How do you balance importance of `gender` and `days`? Edit: Sorry didn't see you filter on gender. So its a hierarchical merge, where you filter on gender first then get the closest days match?

Comment: @JonnyPhelps you are correct - hierarchical merge, giving `gender` priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Data

First of all, I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your input dataframes because it is easier to work with strings than factors with my solution.

```
df1 <- data.frame(group = rep("A", 5),
              name = c("Brandon",
                       "Kyler",
                       "Trent",
                       "Lesa",
                       "Michael"),
              gender = c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M"),
              days = c(50, 45, 32, 60, 48),
              stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(group = rep("B", 10),
                  name = c("Erica", 
                           "Jared",
                           "Sara",
                           "Helen",
                           "Tom",
                           "Ron",
                           "Cy",
                           "Lynn",
                           "Ken",
                           "Judy"),
                  gender = c("F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F"),
                  days = c(47, 49, 62, 80, 74, 30, 55, 58, 63, 25),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

### Solution

```
library(tidyverse)

# empty dataframe for the output
df2_new <- data.frame(group = character(),
                      name = character(),
                      gender = character(),
                      days = numeric(),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){

  # add the row of interest to the output dataframe
  df2_new[i,] <- df2 %>% 
    mutate(day_diff = abs(days - df1$days[i])) %>%
    filter(gender == df1$gender[i]) %>% 
    slice(which.min(day_diff)) %>%
    select(-day_diff)

  # remove the newly added row from the original dataset
  df2 <- df2 %>%
    filter(!(name %in% df2_new$name))

}
```

This is the first solution that came to mind. In this case, rows are deleted from `df2` as the for cycle goes on, as you said that you

> want to filter `df2` to include only the closest match to each row in the `df1`

### Output

```
df2_new

  group  name gender days
1     B Jared      M   49
2     B Erica      F   47
3     B   Ron      M   30
4     B  Sara      F   62
5     B    Cy      M   55
```

In my case the code picked Sara instead of Lynn, but it's a 50/50 choice.